# PHP JSON array from SQLite3

Tags: php, json, sqlite

I'm trying convert data from a SQLite3 db to a JSON array by using PHP. I'm getting close, but I can't seem to get it right.

This is the error I'm getting:
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::fetchAll() expects parameter 1 to be long, object given in...

Thanks!

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:example.db');

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test');

$json = array();

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($data = $result->fetchall($result)){

$x = $data['Time'];
$y = $data['Temperature'];

$json[] = array( (int($x)), (int($y)) );
}
?>
```

Comment: Try removing the line with `$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, and do this on the while line: `while ($data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: You don't call `fetchAll` in a loop, it returns all the results at once as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Good point, the call should be `$result->fetch()`, not `$result->fetchAll()`. Alternatively, you could call `$data = $result->fetchAll()` first, then turn the while loop into a foreach loop.

Answer (score 4):

Got it working now. Thanks for your help!

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite:example.db');

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test');

$datapie = array();

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

extract($row);

$datapie[] = array(floatval($Temperature), $Time);
}

$data = json_encode($datapie);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$result->fetchall($result)
```

to:

```
$result->fetch()
```

You had two problems: the argument to `fetchAll()` should be a fetch mode, not a result. And `fetchAll()` returns all the rows, not one row at a time. If you're calling in a loop you use `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

PDO's fetchAll function, doesn't expect the query itself as a param.

Check it's manual here - you can leave it blank, or set the fetch mode:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php